# Distance between 2 circles with same radius to overlap a desired percentage?

Tags: geometry

I want to draw 2 circles of the same size that have a specified percentage of area overlapping.

For instance, if the overlapping percentage is 0%, the circles are next to each other and the distance between the centers is equivalent to the radius. If the overlapping percentage is 100%, they are completely on top of each other (looking like 1 circle), and the distance between the centers is 0. If the overlapping percentage is 50% they intersect so that 50% of their area is overlapping.

**What is an equation that, given the percentage of area two circles should overlap, tells you the distance the centers of the circles need to be from each other?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a straightforward but messy exercise to find the area of the "lens" formed by the intersection of the two circles.  If the radii are the same, consider a circle with center $(0,0)$ and radius 1 and another with center $(d,0)$ and radius $1$. Then the area of the lens divided by $\pi$ is the percentage you are looking for.  The circles are

$$C_0: \ \ x^2+y^2 = 1,\ \ \ C_d: \ \ (x-d)^2 +y^2 = 1.$$

Solving for the intersection points we find

$$ P_1 = (d/2,\sqrt{4 - d^2}/2 , \ \ P_2 = (d/2,-\sqrt{4 - d^2}/2) $$

The segment $P_1 P_2$ is a chord that cuts both circles.  You can find formulas for the area between each circle and the chord -- then add them to obtain the area of the lens.

The area between the chord and $C_0$ is

$$A_0 = \arccos(d/2)- d\sqrt{4 - d^2}/4.$$

The area between the chord and $C_d$ is identical by symmetry

$$A_d = \arccos(d/2)- d\sqrt{4 - d^2}/4.$$

Hence the percentage of overlap is

$$O = \frac{2 \arccos(d/2)- d\sqrt{1 - d^2/4}}{\pi}.$$

In order to find $d$ for a specified value of $O$, you have to solve a non-linear equation numerically. There is no closed form solution.

If $O = 0.5$ then $d = 0.8079455...$ approximately.

Comment: It looks like that equation tells you the area given the distance, but I need to solve for d.

Comment: Sure -- need area given distance first.

Comment: There is no closed form solution for d as a function of O.  If you want to solve for d in some practical application then you can use a numerical procedure like the Newton-Raphson method. I used Wolfram alpha to solve for d when the overlap is 50%.

Comment: FWIW, I just wrote a short interactive Python program to do this calculation using Newton-Raphson. I'll post a link containing the code in the next comment (the program's encoded in the URL). The program runs on a Sage server, but it only uses plain Python to do the calculation, although it does use Sage to plot a diagram, and to handle the interactivity.

Comment: Click [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxtUstugzAQvPMVq_aATSAF2khtJaR-Qu5VFTlgglUHI9tqk7_vrg15SPUB1jPe2dm1e2uOcBR-AHWcjPXg1JhDa1wOk8pBuVYbJ5PkQ41eWtH6pJM9tMq2Wu7Mj7RaTMwKr0xTrjf8PQFcAhoIGGSoAk9QBxiLNMCq9QZhwSHLcIPkMw9sbywoUCNmjgfJ3mYtWl3MFLAie6zGfD9w0oVijlCpINsLyS_Jk0XrDHvxQ05KVwZVVw1BF0T1S8eso-NlDmLvdt7oZiOL6uXGE629leI7Sa5V-E2c-kF6kca6WCqD6rVEpzTWtJMHK6VLY8IphzM2SPbRXx6aXIzOYhFCQY6K5zsqps3U6Y7qlPNibCUSNJd7MtzQzKAAzu-E0ZkHj_Fk-DzCVhsPyoddW-HzqOk6CrRdolsW_oHcIj4ZVHeMxYN8IXDSWo2SfRLOSmqC-BgXYVN90cvTxjYPVnYPN5nxvQXJ6h-4vsBuML9sy_8A0LW5Qw==&lang=python&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

Answer (score 3):

I get a slightly different answer. Very sorry for not simply submitting a comment, but my neophyte status prohibits that.

I get $$O = \frac{2 \arccos(d/2)- d\sqrt{1 - d^2/4}}{\pi}.$$
I'm sure that was just a quick fraction mess-up. Again, sorry for not just commenting.

Comment: Thanks.  Good catch. I corrected the formulas above. I did use the correct formula in the numerical solution for 50% overlap - d = 0.807...